# Insert space between digit and alphabet on specific column

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

How do I insert a space between column 5 digits and alphabets, the error code should be like that: 
`554 RTR:BL` 
`421 MFF:MT`

```
Timestamp:    EmailTo:          EmailFrom:         IPAddress:      ErrorCodes:
2016-06-19  saadiahk@aol.com Haroon@deignplus.cz  16.23.29.141     554RTR:BL
2016-06-20  saadiahk@aol.com Haroon@knsaifelt.com 13.43.219.141    421MFF:MT
```

Comment: there will total of 3 numbers in last column every time ?

Comment: One alternative: `awk '{print gensub(/^(.*)([0-9]+)([A-Z:]*)$/, "\\1\\2 \\3", "g")}' sourceFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there will be total of 3 digits on 5th column, using GNU `sed` you can do something like,

```
sed -r 's/([^\s]*\s){5}[0-9]{3}/& /' filename
```

**Sample:**

```
$ sed -r 's/([^\s]*\s){5}[0-9]{3}/& /' filename

Timestamp:    EmailTo:          EmailFrom:         IPAddress:      ErrorCodes:
2016-06-19  saadiahk@aol.com Haroon@deignplus.cz  16.23.29.141     554 RTR:BL
2016-06-20  saadiahk@aol.com Haroon@knsaifelt.com 13.43.219.141    421 MFF:MT
```

**Explanation :**

- The first five fields are described by zero or more characters that are not a space separated `[^\s]*` followed by space.
- The error code is described by first 3 digits followed by alphabets. The replacement is everything that is matched `&` with a space added afterwards.

Comment: Can you please share command description.